# Monitoring vi usage

Tags: python, shell

I have a file in which I have stored information about users: username, full name, group, etc.

I have to write a "monitoring" shell script, that saves in a file called `log.txt` all the users (username, full name, group) that execute a vi command more than once per minute. The log file should also contain the time when the vi command was started.

I know that I should use the ps command, but since I'm new to shell scripting, I need Your help.

Comment: Start by running `ps` (and reading `man ps`). Presumably you know python well enough to parse the output of that. Come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: Actually, I don't think `ps` is going to do what you want unless you thrash the hell out of your system.

Comment: Since I don't have experience in shell, I thought this was a specific question. Anyway. Thanks for the answers ...

Comment: For a newbie, this is a non-trival problem. The logic of differentiating between new vi sessions and continuing vi sessions AND then users that start vi more than 1 x per minute makes my wonder 'why on earth would you want to to that!?' ;-). You may have been downvoted because you tagged this w/python, but are asking for shell help. ps is certainly the most straight forward solution to getting information about running processes, but the vendor OS (aixSolEtc) all have different vers and opts, and same is true probably on a lesser scale for Linux. You should tag which OS you are using. GL

Answer (score 1):

Rename /usr/bin/vi.  Put a wrapper script that does your logging and then executes the original vi.

Without more work, users could still run the original vi, but this might help and will certainly have a lower impact than running 'ps' constantly.